# Laravel multiple get() requests - is there a better solution?

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent

My current project is a kind of internal phone book. A user/administrator can not see and edit all existing contacts, but he can gets permission to edit one or more departments and/or one or more companies (with all linked departments).

- A User belongstoMany companies and/or departments.
- The contacts belongs to a department.
- A department belongs to a company.

I'm working with laravel 5.4 and got the following solution. The results are correct, but it's also efficent and clean enough?

**User class:**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;


/**
 * The companies that can be edited by the users.
 * 
 * @return void
 */

public function companies()
{
    return $this->belongstoMany(Company::class);
}


/**
 * The departments that can be edited by the user.
 * 
 * @return void
 */

public function departments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Department::class);
}


/**
 * Get all contacts that can be edited by the user.
 * 
 * @return void
 */

public function allContacts()
{
    // Open a new collection
    $contacts = collect();

    // Get all contacts that belongs to all departments
    $this->departments()->get()->each(function ($item) use (&$contacts) {
        $contacts = $contacts->merge(Department::find($item->id)->contacts()->get());
    });

    // Get all contacts that belongs to all companies
    $this->companies()->get()->each(function ($item) use (&$contacts) {
        $contacts = $contacts->merge(Company::find($item->id)->contacts()->get());
    });

    // Return a unique collection
    return $contacts->unique();
}
}
```

**ContactsController:**

```
/**
 * Display a listing of editables contacts.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $contacts = Auth()->user()->allContacts();
    return view('contacts.index', compact('contacts'));
}
```

Is the multiple use of get() and each() in the *allContacts*-method a good way? I tried to use as much eloquent and collection functions as possible. Or is a raw sql the better solution?

Thanks for your support and great ideas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is bad because the code you use will generate too many queries and the code itself is not readable.

Use nested [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) instead. An example:

```
$contacts = Contact::whereHas('department.user', function($q) {
    $q->where('id', auth()->id());
})
->orWhereHas('department.company', function($q) {
    $q->whereHas('user', function($q) {
        $q->where('id', auth()->id());
    });
})
->get();
```

Comment: It's working after adding some user() methods in the company and department models. But now I'm getting not the correct results.  A user need permission to the company AND the department now. With the permission of the company the user should be able to edit all departments of the company without explicit permission for the department.

Comment: @Texx do you mean after adding relations? Also, second one should be `orWhereHas`.

Comment: That "orWhereHas"-change does the trick! Now I'm fine :) Thank you so much. I added a belongsToMany(User::class) to the company and the department model.